# SAP Business One linking delivery tables to OBTN table

Tags: sql, sapb1

Appreciate if someone could tell me how to join the delivery tables (ODLN, DLN1) to the batch table (OBTN).

Best Regards,

Daniel

Comment: Hi dear @Daneil Carreira. You have to add table difinisiton of ODLN and DLN1 in question. Good luck

Comment: Hi Hamed, they are header and rows tables for delivery document, does this answer your question? Best Regards, Daniel

Comment: Would you show sample data and field names with both tables?

Comment: Hi Daniel, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  IBT1.BatchNum 
, ODLN.DocNum
, DLN1.ItemCode 
, DLN1.Dscription 

FROM ODLN   
INNER JOIN IBT1 on IBT1.BaseType = ODLN.ObjType AND IBT1.BaseNum = ODLN.DocNum
INNER JOIN DLN1 on ODLN.DocEntry = DLN1.DocEntry
```

I think the key is the IBT1 view, the batch number transaction details.

Comment: Hi Sawsine, I am not sure if i can use the IBT1 table, do you know by any chance how to do a join using instead OBTN? Best Regards, Daniel

Comment: IBT1 is a view, not a table. Make sure you include IBT1.BaseType in the ON clause of the join.

Comment: HI Daz many thanks for the info. Best Regards, Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, Daz is right saying it is a view. Let us know how you get on with this. 